# Brackets variable php

Tags: php, parsing, variables, brackets

I dont like to use a template engine in PHP. But i do like to assign {variable} to a PHP variable. How can i convert these variables to a php variable?

I tried to search on stackoverflow etc, nothing is what i mean.

Probally you will suggest use a TPL engine but that is not my question. What should be the right term for this 'function'. I just wanna learn for example with a good tutorial.

`{username}` links to `$user->data()->username`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do yourself what a template engine does? Because a template engine does exactly what you are asking. But you want to write the logic yourself. Am I correct? You are asking how to replace `{username}` USING php? Or am I misunderstanding.

Comment: You need a combination of a parser together with a compiler. That together is called a template engine.

Comment: May be it can help you http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to roll your own basic templating you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$string = 'Hello {username} Today is {fulldate}';
$search = ['{username}', '{fulldate}'];
$replace = [$user->data()->username, date(DATE_RFC850)];
$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

It's basic and crude and can be full of gotchcas if you're not careful.  Which is why using a template engine is highly recommended.  They are more powerful and generally safer then rolling your own.